# XML validation againts XSD

Tags: xml, xsd

I am trying to validate my xml document against xsd schema.

I am using this page http://www.freeformatter.com/xml-validator-xsd.html and I get error : "S4s-elt-must-match.1: The Content Of 'sequence' Must Match (annotation?, (element | Group | Choice | Sequence | Any)*). A Problem Was Found Starting At: ComplexType."

Here is the XML http://wklej.org/id/2303662/, here XSD: http://wklej.org/id/2303799/

Can you help me to fix this error? I guess it's a problem with the Address element.

Comment: Please create a [mcve] ***within the body of your question***.  Links to offsite XML and XSDs are unacceptable because those links can break in the future, leaving your question and our answers worthless to future readers.

Answer (score 1):

Replace:

```
<xs:element name="Address" type="addressType"/>
<xs:complexType >
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="street" type="streetType"/>
<xs:element name="home" type="homeType"/>
<xs:element name="city" type="cityType"/>
<xs:element name="country" type="countryType"/>
<xs:element name="code" type="codeType"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:complexTypeType name="addressType">
</xs:complexTypeType>
```

with:

```
<xs:element name="Address" type="addressType"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:complexType name="addressType">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="street" type="streetType"/>
<xs:element name="home" type="homeType"/>
<xs:element name="city" type="cityType"/>
<xs:element name="country" type="countryType"/>
<xs:element name="code" type="codeType"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

The schema should then be valid.

The xml file won't be valid though, as

```
<code>72-864</code>
```

doesn't match the expected pattern in your schema:

```
<xs:pattern value="[0-9]{5}(-[0-9]{4})?"/>
```

I don't know which is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the following:

```
<xs:element name="person">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:element name="firstname" type="namesType"/>
            <xs:element name="lastname" type="namesType"/>
            <xs:element name="birthdate" type="birthType"/>
            <xs:element name="PESEL" type="peselType"/>
            <xs:element name="sex" type="sexType"/>
            <xs:element name="Address" type="addressType"/>
            <xs:complexType >
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="street" type="streetType"/>
                    <xs:element name="home" type="homeType"/>
                    <xs:element name="city" type="cityType"/>
                    <xs:element name="country" type="countryType"/>
                    <xs:element name="code" type="codeType"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:complexType name="addressType">
</xs:complexType>
```

With:

```
    <xs:element name="person">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:element name="firstname" type="namesType"/>
                <xs:element name="lastname" type="namesType"/>
                <xs:element name="birthdate" type="birthType"/>
                <xs:element name="PESEL" type="peselType"/>
                <xs:element name="sex" type="sexType"/>
                <xs:element name="Address" type="addressType"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
<xs:complexType name="addressType">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="street" type="streetType"/>
        <xs:element name="home" type="homeType"/>
        <xs:element name="city" type="cityType"/>
        <xs:element name="country" type="countryType"/>
        <xs:element name="code" type="codeType"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

And as ChrisC said, the  element won't validate with the current pattern.